# How to display a grid system on adobe muse for easier design?

Tags: grids, adobe-muse

I downloaded adobe muse and I find it perfect ! However I wonder if there is some plugin or page option or view that can display a grid system on the screen so I can arrange my components easier ? And by grid I mean X,Y grid no only Y grid like 960 grid system.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this would be to set up your Y grid via the page options, and then make your grid by turning on the ruler Ctrl+R and then creating your own horizontal line guides to complete your grid.

I know its not the perfect solution, but it can acheive your goal. Especially with the ability to adjust guide placements by direct input, Drag the guide onto your workspace, click it, then at the top of your screen you can manually adjust the X Y position to be exactly as you like it.

Answer (score 0):

http://museresources.com/960-grid.html Try this out. It's a free resource that helps me a good bit.

Comment: Welcome to Graphic Design! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: also, your plugin deals only with Y grid, so it only answers half of the question